# Custom header: [E] \chaptername \thechapter [O] \chaptermark

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm new here and I'm into headers with package `fancyhdr`. 
My request is: I want on even pages, CHAPTER NUMBER, in the odd pages CHAPTERTITLE. So in a way like: [E] `\chaptername \thechapter` [O] `\chaptermark`

I face some issues with `\renewcommand` on `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` that I cant't edit both entry simoultaneously. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,titlepage,openright,fleqn,onecolumn,draft]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm, bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}                                                            
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}{#1}}

\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{CCC1}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\section{SS1}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{CCC2}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\section{SS2}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). Could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we could help you more easily?

Comment: It would help if you could specify **where** the relevant pieces should appear. Left, centered or right?

Comment: Sure, i'm adding a few code lines. i'm feeling a newbie =(

Comment: Don't worry: we've all started at the beginning, and you're here at the right place for your questions!

Comment: You want following hearder, don't you?                                                `[2n]_____Chapter X_|_Chapter-Name_______[2n+1]`

Comment: I want: `pagenumber______Chapter 3` in even pages and `Chaptertitle________pagenumber` in odd pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer provided by Christian Hupfer solves, in a specific way, the issue. But when I've added nomenclature `nomencl` and bibliography `bibtex`, headings become painful. So I discovered `\usepackage{titleps}`, instead of `fancyhdr` that provide simple solution: set up `plain` and `main` pagestyle and other styles builded up eg. for nomenclature and bibliography , changing pagestyle whenever you want.

Comment: I can't solve things which aren't in your 'MWE' -- As your answer implies: My answer is useless for you and I can delete it

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm sorry, next time I'll be more specific. I discovered this issue later. BTW thank you